# JS: Callback function is not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, synchronous

I've following JS Code for form submission,I kept form submission in a function called `submitForm`, so that it will work for multiple forms, by just passing `selector` and `action` values to the `submitForm` function.

```
function submitForm(selector, action, onComplete) {
  var response
  $(selector).submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: action,
      data: data,
      dataType: 'json',
      a
      sync: false,
      success: function (data) {
        response = data;
      }
    });
  });
  return response;
}
submitForm(".lform", "user.php", function (response) { // Callback function
  // Doing necessary stuff
});
```

In above code, callback function is not executing, what might be the reason ? and inside callback function, following code is there,

```
location.reload(); // To refresh the total DOM,
$(".c_form").dialog({
  closeOnEscape: false,
  title: title,
  modal: true,
  close: function () {
    $(this).dialog('destroy').hide();
  }
});
```

I want show dialog box after completion of reload of the page, is it possible ?

Comment: `var response` is not going to be initialized as the function will have already returned before the AJAX request finishes its request.

Answer (score 2):

You **can't** return `response`. At that time, it's still `undefined` because AJAX hasn't placed `data` on it yet.

Your callback function is the third argument `onComplete`. Upon AJAX success, execute it, and pass it `data`:

```
success: function (data) {
  onComplete(data);
}
```

Comment: I've tried how you have suggested its working fine, expect the `reloading` of the page and `dialogbox` issue. Is it possible to make these two work as expected? Thanks

Comment: The problem with your reloading callback is that when you call location.reload() the page reloads and the code after isn't executed because the page is reloaded

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Joseph the Dreamer and also add error callback, your request may has errors and because of that the success call back is not executing, add it just like the success call back :

```
error: function () {
  alert("ERROR!!");
}
```

and also with your code you cant show a dialog this way, you are rendering the dialog after calling reload method and this creates a new DOM elements where the previous page can do nothing to the new page (after reload), my advice is to send a Query string param indicates showing the dialog like `domain.com/smth?show_dialog=1` and in your JS on page load check if this param exists to show the dialog.